# SAS - summing values down observations

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I would like to sum values for a set of observations, for a specific column based on a specific identifier. For example, suppose I have data like the below

```
A 4 5 6
B 3 3 2
A 3 4 2
C 3 2 0
B 3 7 3
B 2 4 1
```

Suppose I want to sum all of the values by the identifier in column 1, so I have totals for A, B and C by a specific column of my choice (2, 3 or 4).
Then in a separate data set just output either A, B or C that is beyond a certain criteria.

For example, I want the sums of column 4 (based on identifier in column 1) which are above the value of 1, my output data set should return A = 8, B = 6, and obviously nothing for C as its zero.

I am open to `Proc SQL`, or the `data` step, in fact it would be useful to know both methods.

Comment: What have you tried? Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, add a where statement after the from for your criteria.

```
proc sql ;
  create table output as
  select Column1, sum(column2) as ColSum2, sum(column3) as ColSum3,
         sum(column4) as ColSum4
  from your_data_table_here
  group by 1
  order by 1
  ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `proc sql` to groupby and sum over columns. Assuming you have data with identifying columns `col1, col2, col3` and a value column `value`:

```
proc sql;
        create table SUMS as
        select COL1, COL2, COL3, sum(VALUE) as VALUE_SUM
        from YOUR_TABLE
        group by COL1, COL2, COL3;
quit;
```

For the Python people among you, this would be analogous to something in Pandas like `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])['value'].sum().rename('value_sum').reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql - groupby - sum aggregate function